# Accessing elements in a json object

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have several questions how to access the json object, but my question is slightly different. my json object looks bit different

this is my json object

```
data = ["data","{\"id\":\"fd00::212:4b00:197b:274a\",\"counter\":30,\"temperature\":2622,\"humidity\":4617,\"battery\":2828,\"timestamp\":\"04:48:50.816305\",\"date\":\"2019-04-26\",\"deviceType\":\"milo\"}"]
```

I want to access elements  with in this json object

```
  realTime() {
    this.webSocket.connect()
      .subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
          console.log(data)
          console.log(data[1].temperature)
          this.device_id = data.id
          this.temperature = data.temperature
          this.humidity = data.humidity
        })

  }
```

I have tried but not able to access the elements properly

Comment: This is not a valid JSON object, as “ are escaped and “data” just stands by itself. Try an online JSON validator/formatter to test the object received, and use JSON.parse in your code, if available

Comment: do the statement 'console.log(data[1].temperature)' print anything?

Comment: `JSON.parse(data[1]).temprature`

Comment: i have tried online viewer, this is the result - 
`JSON
0 : "data"
1 : "{"id":"fd00::212:4b00:197b:274a","counter":30,"temperature":2622,"humidity":4617,"battery":2828,"timestamp":"04:48:50.816305","date":"2019-04-26","deviceType":"milo"}"`

Comment: @karthik_varma_k its prints undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data[1]` holds a JSON string, not an object so you have to parse it using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data[1]).temperature);
```

Final code:

```
realTime() {
    this.webSocket.connect()
      .subscribe((data:any[]) => {
         console.log(data)
         let data1 = JSON.parse(data[1]);
         console.log(data1.temperature)
         this.device_id = data1.id
         this.temperature = data1.temperature
         this.humidity = data1.humidity
      })

}
```

Comment: error  `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse`

Comment: @Chinni :  what's the output of  `console.log(data)`

Comment: worked if i parse data and not data[1]. Thank you !! @pranav

Comment: @Chinni :  maybe `data` holds the JSON string.  But in your question `data` is an array and the second element in the array is a JSON string...

Answer (score 0):

JSON works on key value pair so try using the below solution to do so.

```
realTime() {
    this.webSocket.connect()
      .subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
          console.log(data);
          console.log(data[1]["temperature"]);
          this.device_id = data[1]["id"];
          this.temperature = data[1]["temperature"];
          this.humidity = data[1]["humidity"];
        })

  }
```